# Set the line to be read in Perl IO::File

Tags: perl, file-io

How can I change the position of the pointer in a file handle in terms of line number (not bytes)?

I want to set the first line to beginning reading a file.  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Well I already google searched but couldn find. I don want to set the pointer in terms of bytes using tell, seek, sysseek. I want to do that in terms of line number in a easy way. If you know you just could answer.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with a file whose lines all have the same number of bytes, then how could you possibly set the position via line number alone?

Comment: [facepalm] And the answer is: you don't.  You don't have enough information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the file pointer is not a purpose to itself. If you want to read a certain line, use [Tie::File](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile).

```
use Tie::File qw();
tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'thefilename' or die $!;
print $file[2]  # 3rd line
```

Comment: This reads the whole content of the file into your variable named file, if I am not mistaken. Question: What if the file is very big and somebody wants to read two lines from the end? Is it necessary to load the whole file into memory and then get the needed rows, or is there a better way?

Comment: So the best way to read from an arbitrary line to the end is iterating over the array? like: `my $i = 1000; while($i < scalar @file){ print $file[$i]; $i++; }` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm alien to Perl, but I'm interested in any question of any technology, I apologize if my question in my previous comment was trivial.

Comment: @nsbm: yes, or `print for @file[1000..$#file]`

Answer (score 4):

Use `tell` and `seek` to read and write the position of each line in your file. Here's a possible solution that requires you to pass through the whole file, but doesn't require you to load the whole file into memory at once:

```
# make a pass through the whole file to get the position of each line
my @pos = (0);   # first line begins at byte 0
open my $fh, '<', $the_file;
while (<$fh>) {
    push @pos, tell($fh);
}
# don't close($fh)


# now use  seek  to move to the position you want
$line5 = do { seek $fh,$pos[4],0; <$fh> };

$second_to_last_line = do { seek $fh,$pos[-3],0; <$fh> };
```

Comment: That `@pos` cache is how the core module [Tie::File](http://p3rl.org/Tie::File) works internally.